# Visual Studio 2012 no autocompletion during variable instantiation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, intellisense

While variable instantiation code is being written by the programmer, IntelliSense should display an appropriate autocomplete suggestion based on the variable type, right? But it does not work in my IDE (Visual Studio 2012 with Visual Basic programming presets).

Let's say I declared a variable in Visual Basic

```
Dim myList As List(Of String)
```

and I start writing instantiation code

```
myList = New
```

At this point IntelliSense should show me a suggestion of 'List(Of String)', but it doesn't. I always have to write the complete type name manually. Is there a way to fix it?

I remember that it worked for a while just after I installed VS2012, but it stopped either after I changed programming presets to Visual Basic or after I installed some external components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting it...

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General
and enable Auto List Members and Parameter Information in right hand side pane.

If that doesn't work try this below...

Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.

EDIT

1: Close all the tabs and open your file again.

2: Clean the Build > Close the Solution > Restart Visual Studio > Open the Solution again

3: Goto: Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache

4: Close Visual Studio 2012 and delete this folder: %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas

Comment: I've just checked both the solutions you suggested, but unfortunately neither fixed the issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please see edit, it can be numerous reasons we've had this happen more than once before.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. I even tried uninstalling CodeRush for VisualStudio, but that didn't help too.